# Is Firebase's new Firestore DB more expensive for an e-commerce android app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, e-commerce

I'm stuck between Firebase Real Time database and Firestore for my e-commerce app. I want to know which one is cheaper. I know there will be alot of reads in an e-commerce app, does this make Firestore more expensive?

Answer (score 0):

The billing models for Cloud Firestore and the Firebase Realtime Database are completely different. It is impossible to say which one will be cheaper/more expensive, without have a very clear list of precisely how your app interacts with the database. Once you have such a list, it is actually quite simple to put the numbers into the price model, and compare the two.

Also note that the data model you pick has a large effect on the price. If you're new to NoSQL databases in general or Firestore specifically, I highly recommend checking out the video series [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ), specifically the episodes on [pricing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NegFl9p_sE&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=4&t=228s) and [how to structure your data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haMOUb3KVSo&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=5).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data relationship and how you use database. And you have to know the nature of your technology you’ll be using.

You READ/WRITE lots of data, Firebase Cloud-Firestore’s cost will be so expensive. Realtime database doesn’t care when you READ/WRITE Data.